# Trouble with specifying parent dependency in npm package.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package.json

I am having an issue with trying to specify a specific parent dependency for a package to use in place of another.
example:

```html
dependencys: {
  dependencyA
  dependencyB
  dependencyC
}
```

dependencyA is an older version of a newer package with a different name but is an update to the older package. we can call this newDependencyA.

when I include newDependencyA in the dependencys list in the package.json file conflicts occurr. I am in need of this new updated dependency named newDependencyA as a parent dependency of dependencyC.

when I try to remove the old dependencyA and replace it with the new one dependencyB errors because it is trying to import the old dependencyA using the old name.

I was not sure if there was a way to specify parent dependencies in place of another. I want to specify dependencyC to use newDependencyA and not dependencyA

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: This solution does not work. The package having the conflicts still has an issue. Also this command does not install any of the conflicting dependencies for the package that I am trying to use